# How to create a new list that excludes a list from the main list used

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a main list that I am using:
[image: Main List]

I am currently trying to filter out the main list by ensuring that the main list does not contain any entry from the "Do not add list" as shown in this image:
[image: Do not add list]

My attempt to solve this issue was to create a new list by using an If statement and name range:

=IF(List1=List2,"",List1) . (The name range of List1 is referring to the Main list and the List2 name range is referring to the "Do not add list".

As a result I had the following output:

[image: New list]

The new list contains ABCD still even though it is not supposed to be since it is on the do not add list. Any help on being able to create a filtered main list is appreciated.

Comment: Are you on `Excel-2010`? Latest version will make it easier to solve the issue.

Comment: Actually I have Microsoft 365 Excel.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=FILTER(A2:A8,COUNTIF(B2:B6,A2:A8)=0)
```

Comment: Simple and cleaner one.

Answer (score 1):

I you can use VLOOKUP to check if it exists:
[image]

The Do not add list defined as List2
,The formula is:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A3,List2,1,0)),A3,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FILTER()` formula like-

```
=FILTER(A2:A17,NOT(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2:A17,$D$4:$D$17,0))))
```

[image]